# Meaning of certifi package being updated and ca-certificates and openssl being superseded

Tags: python, conda, channel

I happily install python packages on a regular basis, and somehow these packages below end up being updated or superseded. I never asked myself, what they do, but I am curious. Why is the `certify` package updated so much, and what does it mean when `ca-certificates` and `openssl` are superseded by a higher-priority channel? FWIW, I install packages from normal conda and conda-forge channels in the same environment.

````
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  certifi            pkgs/main::certifi-2020.12.5-py37haa9~ --> conda-forge::certifi-2020.12.5-py37h03978a9_1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2021.1.19-~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2020.12.5-h5b45459_0
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1i-h2bbff1b_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1i-h8ffe710_0```
````

Comment: this question might be better suited for the [security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: the latter cleared it up, thank you!